# Spring JPA Repository to be multi-client capable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to build a application with spring that is multi-client capable.
The best thing I can think of would be to have two entities.
One which is valid for all clients (normal entity)

```
@Entity
public class Address {
}
```

and the entity that is somehow restricted to only show / delete / update / insert data for that client (filtered with WHERE client_id = ?)

```
@Entity
@SomeFilter("WHERE client_id = ?")
public class AddressClient {
}
```

For the later the JPA Spring Repository with the findAll method would only return entries for that client. The insert method would automatically add the client_id and the update and delete method would also only operate on client_id data.

The client_id should be taken from the default Spring UserDetails object associated with each session.

Is there a good way to achieve this or do I have to add methods to each repository to include the client_id filter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "multi-client capable"?  Do you mean that the same application deployment should be able to serve multiple customers of yours and that each customer should get access to only their data?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to filter data according to the permission of an user. Then you should look at the annotations '@PostFiler' and '@PreFilter'.

Comment: @manish yes you are right. its about multiple customers using the same application but only see their data. Each table has a eg. client_id by which we could filder.

Comment: @RenéWinkler they look like the thing I need except its not the exact use case. Imagine we have many thousend customers with hundreds of addresses....  I don't think that post and preFilter will perform? I have to load like 10'000 addresses and then filter out 9'900 out? doesn't sound right. If spring security uses this annotation to integrate into the query that would be perfect. is this the case?

Comment: You are looking for [multi-tenancy support in Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html).  There are many ways to implement this.  Hibernate supports three different ways, each explained on the article I have linked.